# How to get the path of .app file in Mac machine after build in VS for Mac 2019?

Tags: ios, xamarin, ui-testing, visual-studio-mac

I've noticed that with Visual Studio for Mac 2019 it now generates an extra device-builds folder inside a bin/Debug for iOS project.

Does anybody know how to get the correct path to .app file or maybe there are some configs exists to make it more generic?

Answer (score 0):

> /Users/username/workspace/{ProjectName}/{ProjectName}.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.8-12.2/{AppName}.iOS.app

or you can use terminal:

> mdfind {AppName}.iOS.app

Comment: I need to get .app file using C# code. iphone11.8-12.2 is not generic path, if I build solution on another simulator the system will create folder with other numbers.